# Single tap to activate button in UITableView Swift Storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard

I Have a `UITableView` with sections and rows, one cell for sections and another one for rows.

[image]

Each Section got one `UIButton` that is just a normal + "image". First time I open the app I need to click this button twice for it to react, after that it reacts on the first tap every single time.

Does anyone have a good solution to this or is it an Emulator bug?

Comment: Can you share some gif of the problem or the screenshot of the screen for a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Ofc, sorry for late respond. Moved to new apartment today!

Comment: I was not allowed to post the pic because I'm a new member. But link on image is in post now.

Comment: We get that you are clicking the `+` button. But can you explain the behavior of the app on the first launch and when you click twice the first time and then how the app works? We want to understand on `+` what actually happens so that we can help you.

I mean do you open and close the section on `+` button each time or do you open new window on `+` button?

Comment: My bad! When I click it a UItextfield becomes first responder, and the text I put in there is a new row added to a section with + on it. 
It’s just the first time pressing it after starting app that it needs to be clicked twice to add. After that all lists register the first click. These sections and rows are coredata if that info is useful.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you want to achieve. A small demo gif will help us a lot to understand your issue. Can you add that?